# Adding multiple AdViews onto a ListView

Tags: android, listview, admob

I want to build a News App with Ads (Google SDK) in the ListView. I don't know how much Ads there are, because I receive the content by a Rest API. Every Ad also has a different AdUnitID.

I already tried this solutions:

1. On Android I can set the ViewTypeCount only once (not like in iOS where we can do that dynamically). So I tried to set the viewTypeCount to a high number (manually by Code) and generate a new ViewType for each Ad I got. This is the best workaround, but needs to much CPU usage, also when nearly no Ads are loaded.
2. Tried to use only one Single ViewType for the AdView, but then I cannot change the AdUnitID, because there is a Limitation on the AdView, that this parameter can be set only once. So I need to create a new View for every Ad.

Does anyone has a solution how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was not the High Number of ViewTypes, Problem were the AdViews what consumed a lot of CPU.

I used this workaround: http://pzoleeblogen.wordpress.com/2014/07/08/android-how-to-solve-adview-cpu-consuming/ what works perfectly on all Devices, excepting Android 4.4.x

Answer (score 1):

Usually what I do is create a base class ListItem which implements ListItemInterface. I then have all my ListView items (in your case both News and your Ad wrapper) extend the ListItem. The items then generate their own Views on the fly.

As you get news and ads from your REST, create new News or Ad objects, add them to your List and call adapater.notifyDataSetChanged().

If you think this solution would work for you but have more questions, I'd be happy to clarify (I'm using something similar for a few of my feed-based apps).

```
 public abstract class ListItem implements ListViewInterface{}

 public interface ListItemInterface{
     View getView(Context context, LayoutInflater inflater);
 }

public class ListItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    List<ListItem> listItems;

    public ListItemAdapter(Context context, List<ListItem> listItems){
        this.context = context;
        this.listItems = listItems;
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ListItem item = listItems.get(i);
        return item.getView(context, LayoutInflater.from(context));
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured out that not the Number of ListViews are the Problem. The Problems are the Animations within the AdViews: http://pzoleeblogen.wordpress.com/2014/07/08/android-how-to-solve-adview-cpu-consuming/